# Bounty Custom Message Box Has Display Errors

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I was starting a bounty on one of my questions today. When I went to enter a custom message the box changed some of the text and cut off the left edge.

See Screenshot Below:

[image: Screenshot of Error]

I am running v22 of Firefox. I do not know if this happens in other browsers.

Comment: v22 of... ?????

Comment: @Undo - Sorry, I swear I typed Firefox. Corrected.